# Redefinition of formal parameters C++

Tags: c++

Let me try and change my approach. I have the following code which I would despearatly like to convert into functions. However, whenever I try and use a function structure my variable start to generate error. Thank you to all who have provided me with support thus far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
void names(string names[9]);
void grades(double scores[10][5]);
void getData(double scores[10][5]);


void getData(int scores[10][5])
{

}

void names(string names[9])
{


}

void grades(double scores[10][5])
{

}

int main()
{
//create a string of names to run parallel to thestring containg the students average
string names[9] = { "Johnson", "Aniston", "Cooper", "Blair",
    "Clark", "Kennedy", "Bronson", "Sunny", "Smith" };

int scores[10][5] = { { 85, 83, 77, 91, 76 },
{ 80, 90, 95, 93, 48 },
{ 78, 81, 11, 90, 73 },
{ 92, 83, 30, 69, 87 },
{ 23, 45, 96, 38, 59 },
{ 60, 85, 45, 39, 67 },
{ 77, 31, 52, 74, 83 },
{ 93, 94, 89, 77, 97 },
{ 79, 85, 28, 93, 82 },
{ 85, 72, 49, 75, 63 } };


// Calculate the grades per student and store to the "grades" string
double sum = 0;
double avg = 0;
double grades[10];
//start at the first student.Then move to the next after the average has been computed. 
for (int row = 0; row < 11; row++)
{

    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
    {
        //calculate the sum so it can bedevided by 5
        sum += scores[row][col];
    }
    avg = sum / 5;
    //load the students average into an array
    grades[row] = avg;
    //reset the average so that it does not compound
    sum = 0;
    avg = 0;
}

//print names
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{

    cout << names[i] << endl;
}


//print grades

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    cout << grades[i] << endl;
}
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You can't declare a local variable with the same name as a parameter. Also, you can't copy arrays by assigning them; you have to use something like `memcpy` or `std::copy` or just write a loop yourself.

Comment: @BrianBi I need to establish an array for the students names, I need to create a 2-dimensional array for their grades and then compute the average and load it onto another simple array. How would I go about that without assigning local variables with the same name?

Comment: If you want more detailed help, you should edit your question to make it more clear what each function is supposed to do.

Comment: I hope those aren't real names/grades ;-)

Comment: I have been doing research all day.. Im extremly new to c++. All im trying to do is Use three arrays: a one-dimensional array to store the students’ names, a(parallel) two-dimensional array to store the test scores, and a parallel one-dimensional array to store grades. Using a function to read and store data into two arrays, a function to calculate the average test score and grade, and a function to output the results.

Comment: @user3285237: It would probably help you a lot to go back to more basic stuff like scope of a variable, or the purpose of and how to use functions.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier. This program runs perfectly when i place all the functions in the main(), however I was tasked with using three arrays within fuctions located outside of the Main(). I am currently attending a c++ class and have this task. I have spent over 8 hours on this code, almost all of which being devoted to getting these functions working.

Answer (score 2):

In these functions

```
void getData(int scores[10][5])
{
int scores[10][5] = { { 85, 83, 77, 91, 76 },
//...
```

and

```
 void names(string names[9])
{
string names[9] = { "Johnson", "Aniston", "Cooper", "Blair",
    "Clark", "Kennedy", "Bronson", "Sunny", "Smith" };
//...
```

you declared local variables in the outer most scope of the functions' bodies the same way as the names of their parameters. (For example in the first function the parameter name is scores and the local variable is also defined as having the same name scores) The C++ Standard considers such code as ill-formed.

Also it is not clear why you want to redefine these function parameters.

Also at first you declared function names as having an int array as its parameter

```
void names(int names[9]);
```

and below you defined it as having a string array as its parameter.

```
void names(string names[9])
```

Also in main neither **names** nor **grades** is defined.

Your code has no sense.

At least I think that instead of function names you had to define an array with this name in function main.

Comment: Add to that that `grades()` goes beyond the bounds of `scores` which has only 10 elements.

Comment: I have been doing research all day.. Im extremly new to c++. 
All im trying to do is Use three arrays: a one-dimensional array to store the students’ names, a(parallel) two-dimensional array to store the test scores, and a parallel one-dimensional array to store grades. Using a function to read and store data into two arrays, a function to calculate the average test score and grade, and a function to output the results.

Comment: @Benjamin Bannier I also saw this but in any case it is not clear what his program should to do. For example either elements of the arrays have to be entered or arrays can be simply initialized.

Comment: @user3285237 So start your program with defining the arrays in the main and then step by step add functions the program requires.

Comment: @user3285237 Why do you need separate names and grades arrays? You could consider using a `struct` or `class` containing those two pieces of data? I believe that a `class` is more common if you also want to allow the construct to have functions, which might help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work better.
It starts by creating a `class` named student (don't be confused with a class OF students!)
and then goes on to define functions that can be used to access private values within the class, and three constructors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class student
{
    private:
    std::string name_;
    int scores_[5]; // A vector here might be more useful, if you might add more scores later.
    // eg.
    // std::vector<int> scores_;

    double grade_;

    void storeGrade()
    {
         int sum = 0;
         for (int i=0; i<5; i++) // if using a vector, you could write this with iterators,
         // using scores_.begin(), scores_.end etc
         {
              sum+=scores_[i];
         }
         grade_=(sum/5); // using a counter within the loop would be better if you might have different numbers of scores
     }

     public:
     std::string getName()
     {
          return name_;
     }

     double getGrade()
     {
          return grade_;
     }

     void setScore(int score, int position)
     {
          // with vectors, I think you can use score_.push_back(score) here
          // using instead an array of ints, you need the second parameter, position
          score_[position] = score;
     }

     // Constructors, taking three different sets of parameters.

    student(std::string name)
    {
        name_=name;
    }

    student(std::string name, int score)
    {
        name_=name;
        score_[0]=score;
    }

    student(std::string name, int score[5])
    {
        name_=name;
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) // Not sure if this is strictly necessary, but should work fine
        {
            score_[i]=score[i];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
     student John(John, {95, 17, 20, 56, 28}) // not sure if this will pass as a score[], but if not, 
     //you can pass a real array, or use John(John); and then use John.setScore(...);
     John.storeGrade();
     double JohnsGrade = John.getGrade();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am looking into your suggestions, as well as reading about the use of vectors.